# What inner tube do I need for this tyre?

Tags: tire, innertube

[image: The tyre on my bike]

Can anyone tell me what spec inner tube I need for this tyre? I discovered the one I'd previously bought didn't look fat enough when I got my first puncture with it the other day, now I'm in the process of getting the kit I need to quickly fix punctures on the way to work.

Thanks very much!
John.

Comment: Is there a metric equivalent? Finding one for my road bike was easy but this seems to be a weird tyre..

Comment: Keep in mind that tubes can cover a fairly wide range of tires.  The same tube generally fits 27" and 700 (28") tires, and typically a width range will be speced something like 28-37 mm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like 28 x 1 3/8 (although I did have to squint a bit!), or 700 x 35 if you prefer metric. I think they're pretty standard, I seem to remember having a hybrid that had this size wheel.

For example, the first result on a google search shows one on [Amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Kenda-Tube-35-40-Presta-valve/dp/B0011HW086/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1362649715&sr=8-2). That particular one is a Kenda but I'd lay odds that all the main manufacturers will make this size.

As regards an on-the-road fix, I carry a repair kit (glue & patches) but to be honest would only use if absolutely necessary. Its pretty cheap, and certainly easier, to carry a spare tube. That plus a couple of levers, plus a small pump or CO2, should get you home. I like to carry some disposable latex gloves as well, just to minimise how mucky I get.

If you start getting regular punctures, look more at what tyres you're riding.

Comment: Well it's the first puncture I've had with this bike.. totally agree about having spare tubes.. trying to patch a hole is frustrating, time consuming and mucky. Good idea about the gloves too!

Comment: Yes, 622 is 700c. As a general rule, it's safer to use the ISO/ERTRO measurement, though it doesn't matter as much for inner tubes as it does for tyres (the wrong "28 inch" tyre won't fit the rim, but a 28" tube will stretch).

http://sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html